# How to use a "Page Control" using Xcode 4.2 and storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm trying to learn the basics of iOS programming and I was wondering how you would use a page control using Xcode 4.2 and storyboard? I'm subscribed to MyCodeTeacher.com and the lesson on Page Controllers is outdated and doesn't work with the new Xcode. I cant find a tutorial via Google and the Apple Documentation isn't helping either.
Can someone point me to a good tutorial or give me a basic example?

Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok here is a workflow for a typical case:

1.Create an IBOutlet for your pageControl object

Example:

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
```

2.Create an IBAction as well for the "Value Changed" event of the same pageControl

Example:

```
-(IBAction)pageDidChange:(id)sender;
```

Every time the user changes the page now, your **pageDidChange:** method will be fired.

Now, here are some common methods:

1. **Setup the number of pages**

   `[self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:6];`
2. **Set the current page**

   `[self.pageControl setCurrentPage:1];`

I hope that this will get you started...

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about adding a view to each page?

Comment: The pageControl does not "hold" any views. A typical scenario would be a scrollView containing several views inside it and a pageControl to help with the paging (google "uiscrollview paging" and you should find enough material.

Answer (score 0):

for adding view to each page use scrollview along with page control

```
- (IBAction)changePage {

CGRect frame;

    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;

 frame.origin.y = 0;

frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

 [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```